# Attribute Properties that accept model expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, lambda

I have a model with attributes, and these attributes refer to eachother in string form. eg.

```
public MyModel
{
    [MyAttribute(BindTo = "Foo2")]
    public string Foo1 { get; set; }

    public string Foo2 { get; set; }
}
```

These field names are later used in javascript to pick eachother out on the DOM via name selectors, but is there a way to use expressions to prevent property name changes from breaking the selectors? In a more complicated model it could be forgotten about.

I would like to achieve:

```
[MyAttribute(BindTo = m => m.Foo2)]
```

Is this possible? How could I achieve it? So far I'm at a loss.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider not using attributes in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not possible. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Attribute parameters are restricted to constant values of the
>   following types:
>
> - Simple types (bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double)
> - string
> - System.Type
> - enums
> - object (The argument to an attribute parameter of type object must be a constant value of one of the above types.)
> - One-dimensional arrays of any of the above types

But you can do something like this:

```
[MyAttribute(BindMethod = "GetBinding")]
public string Foo1 { get; set; }

public Expression GetBinding()
{
    Expression<Func<MyModel, string>> expr = m => m.Foo2;
    return expr;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Accepted as answer since provided documentation quote, although I won't be using your alternate solution since it just creates its the problem it is trying to remedy.

Comment: @Tim yeah, I admit it's really not a good solution for your problem. I've done things like that only when some sophisticated logic in the function that the attribute is pointing to (Something like the `CustomValidationAttribute` class).

Answer (score 2):

This unfortunately isn't possible.  C# attributes can accept a very limited set of values.  Essentially anything that is legal to put into a C# `const` value plus some extensions for arrays.  Expression tree lambdas aren't allowed as attribute arguments